# json_decode Does Not Work Properly

Tags: php, json, decode

I have an issue with decoding JSON data.
Does somebody have any idea why the variable `$clanid` is not set?

This is the code:

```
$url = "http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=48000";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($data->clanList as $clan) {

$clanid = $clan->id;
echo $clan->id;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Protip: `var_dump($data);`. Is it what you expected?

Comment: Why pass `true` and not have any idea what it is doing?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/json_decode  2nd argument: `When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.`. you're forcing PHP to return an array, and then try to treat that array as an object.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument for json_decode takes a boolean. If set to true, if forces the output as an array. It defaults to false, which will decode to an object, which is what you require

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata); //removed boolean arg
```

Comment: You are right. json_decode($jsondata, true); will only return an array instead of objects

Comment: Explanation: since the second parameter sets that the json will be converted into an associative array instead of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling json_decode with true as second parameter, your json object is decodec into an associative array and not an object and therefore the foreach should be

```
foreach($data['clanList'] as $clan
```

Have a look at [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrieve as object. Its not possible because ur decoding second parameter says json output is in associative array. Follow the below code

```
   <?php
//get the result from the url by using file_get_contents or curl
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=48000");
//decode the json in associative array by putting true as second parameter
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//fixed array is chosen, clanList is fixed so stored clanList in $in
    $in=$data['clanList'];
//for each element of clanList as key=>value nothing but "element":"value"
//for subarray in clanList use another foreach
    foreach ($in as $key=>$value) {
//to fetch value of element for each key          
    $clanid = $in[$key]['id'];
    echo $clanid;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've one immediate error and one potential error.

json_decode() with a second param `true` will return an associative array (if it can).  Therefore your foreach (and other references) should use array indexes not object fields.

Adding `true` seems intentional so I'll assume you wished to use the data as an associative array and not as an object.  You could of course just remove the `true` param.

Since you have an external data source you might still get errors. For example json_decode() could also return false on invalid JSON.

If you're on php 5.5 you can use [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to retrieve the message.  Otherwise you can fall back to [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

The correct, (mostly) error proof code would look like:

```
$url = "http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=48000";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
if($data === false) { // check for JSON errors as well.
    die(json_last_error());
}

foreach ($data['clanList'] as $clan) { // use array syntax here.
    $clanid = $clan['id']; // Use array syntax here.
    echo $clanid;
}
```

*edit: added note about also possibly removing `true` as per other suggestions*

Comment: the right way is to use true to convert to array. because file_get_contents is unable to convert the result to a object. but if you use cURL instead of file_get_contents then you can handle everything as object: $clan->id

Answer (score 0):

first you should check if the json is returned and then extract it. the problem is when the json is decoded will become 0, 1, 2, 3, etc and you will be unable yo get the clanList. for this you need to use array_values

```
$url = "http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=48000";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$get_indexes = array_values($data);

if ($jsondata) {
    foreach ($get_indexes as $clan) {
    $clanid = $data[$clan]['id'];
    echo $clanid;
    }   
} else {
exit("failed to load stream");
}
```